# What's the algorithm used in bm.calc_volume()?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-printing, mathematics

I need to know which algorithm is used in bm.calc_volume() (https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.calc_volume) or which theorem is based on. It only says it's based on face normals and I haven't been able to find more information.

It would be also useful if someone could help me to find its code.

Comment: This might help. On page two: http://chenlab.ece.cornell.edu/Publication/Cha/icip01_Cha.pdf

Comment: Thank you! But do you know if this is the one that Blender uses?

Comment: No, i don't know that, sorry

Comment: search for `BM_mesh_calc_volume` on [bmesh source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_queries.c)

Comment: Uses the method outlined in link given by @yann .Tessellates the faces, then sums the tetrahedrons.